# How to bind mysqli parameters using loop and store results in array?

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli

```
$genre = array(
    'Action',
    'Adventure',
    'Fantasy'
);
$selectGenre_sql = 'SELECT genreID FROM genres WHERE dbGenre = ?';

if ($stmt->prepare($selectGenre_sql)) {
    // bind the query parameters
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $genre);
    // bind the results to variables
    $stmt->bind_result($genres);
    // execute the query
    $stmt->execute();
    $array1 = array();
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        $array1[] = $genres;
    }
}
```

The code above gets the value from `genreID` when `dbGenre` is equal to `$genre`. And then store the results in an array. But it's not working because `$genre` is an array, so I need to loop through it to get a different value from `genreID` each time.

The 'genres' table contains two columns: **genreID (INT)** and **dbGenre (VARCHAR)**

I just need each genreID (that is a number)... Let's say when dbGenre is equal to Action, then store the genreID in an array1, and then loop the $genre array to get the genreID for the next value and store it again in array1.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't bind an array to an SQL parameter. You can use a parameter in SQL in place of a *single literal value*.  Not a list of values, or an expression, or a column name or table name.

To solve the task in your case, you can use either of two solutions:

**First solution:** loop over `$genre` array, bind each value one at a time and execute the SQL query for each value.

```
$stmt->prepare($selectGenre_sql);
$genre = array();
foreach ($gengre as $genreID) {
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $genreID);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($genres);
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        $genre[] = $genres;
    }
}
```

**Second solution:** execute the query once, with multiple parameters, one for each value in the array.  This requires some tricky code to build a variable number of `?` placeholders in the SQL query, separated by commas.

```
$selectGenre_sql = 'SELECT genreID FROM genres WHERE dbGenre IN ('
 . join(',', array_fill(0, count($genre), '?')) . ')';
```

Also you need to get tricky calling `bind_param()` with a variable number of arguments based on the elements in your `$genre` array:

```
$stmt->prepare($selectGenre_sql);
$temp = array();
foreach ($genre as $key => $value) {
    $temp[] = &$genre[$key];
}

array_unshift($genre, str_repeat('i', count($genre)));
call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_param'), $genre);

$stmt->execute();

$stmt->bind_result($genres);

$array1 = array();
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    $array1[] = $genres;
}
```

You might want to consider using `PDO_MYSQL` because it's easier to bind parameters from an array.  The MySQLi interface is pretty awkward for this case.

Answer (score -1):

A few things.

- Could it be is't because your overwriting the $genre var, try changeing it to $genreArray in the sedond case?
- Make sure that the database is actually returning things (try it in phpMyAdmin or something similar)
- Try processing like this:

.

```
 $genreId = -1;
 $stmt->bind_results($genreId);
 $stmt->execute();
 while($stmt->fetch()){
  $genreArray[] = $genreId;
 }
```

Comment: I just need each genreID (that is a number).... Lets say.. when dbGenre is equal to Action, then store the genreID in the array, and then loop to get the genreID for the next array value..