# SQL handle select with split strings

Tags: php, sql, select, request

I have a request whom looks like this :

```
"SELECT  CLCLEUNIK
,NOM
,VILLE
,CODEP
FROM CLIENT 
WHERE NOM LIKE :nom COLLATE Latin1_general_CI_AI"
```

the :nom is a String, whom can be one word or many words.With php, I want my request to find all the possibility for each words and keep only those in common for each words, but I can't find the way by myself.

I tried to split my string in a String[ ] and do the request for each words, but i don't know how to stock the results in different variables.

Please help me. 
Thanks.

---

Edit

There is my php code :

```
  public function test(Request $request){
    require __DIR__.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR."..".DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR."Entity".DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR."sqlconnect.php";
    $nom = $request->request->has("nom") ? $request->request->get("nom") : "";
    $mots[]=explode(" ", $nom);
    if (sizeof($mots)>1){
      for($i=0; $i>sizeof($mots); $i++){



      }
    }else{
      $req ="SELECT  CLCLEUNIK, NOM, VILLE, CODEP FROM CLIENT WHERE NOM LIKE :nom COLLATE Latin1_general_CI_AI";
      $prepare = $pdo->prepare($req);
      $prepare->execute(
        [
          "nom" => "%{$nom}%"
        ]
      );

      $clientsrecherche = $prepare->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

      foreach($clientsrecherche as $key => $objet){
        foreach($objet as $key2 => $obj){
          $obj=utf8_encode($obj);
          $response[$key][$key2] = $obj;
        };
      }                     
        return new JsonResponse([ "response" => $response]);
    }
   }
```

I don't know what to put in my for.

Comment: if your array's length is >1 you could construct the query as `... WHERE NOM IN (PARAM1,PARAM2...) ...` using a loop

Comment: hi @DIe how do u manage the number of param ? I only see a Switch case with all possibilities but it's a lot of code...

Comment: I don't see the need for a switch statement, neither a problem with the number of parameters (maybe I misunderstood something). In the loop, everytime you add a parameter name (followed by a comma), you also add the parameter itself . Remember removing the last comma and closing parenthesis when exiting the loop and that should be it. If I misunderstood please post and example with 2 or 3 parameters to get the idea

Comment: @DIe my problem is that I don't know how many words will be in my variable, so I don't know how to make my request dynamicaly. I'll put you my php code in my post to show u. Sorry if u don't understand it's my english.

Comment: @DIe the edit is done

Comment: I'm no php guy but I think this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/627763/php-and-mysqli-bind-parameters-using-loop-and-store-in-array) solves the same thing (at least it explains the multiple parameter binding, which it seems is you main problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Juste needed to replace " " by "%" and it's worked